# In Chrome > jQuery flicker when using animate-scrollTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Using the code below works on Firefox, Edge and Chrome mobile, but I can not get the flicker of the element when it reaches the top in latest version of Chrome?

Any ideas what I need to adjust for that browser?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
var $backToTop = $(".back-to-top");
/* this hides the back to top button when the page first loads */
$backToTop.hide();
/* now we need to write a function that makes the back to top button appear after the user has scrolled a certain amount */
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
 if ($(this).scrollTop() > 600) { /* back to top will appear after the user scrolls 600 pixels */
 $backToTop.fadeIn();
 } else {
 $backToTop.fadeOut();
 }
});
/* this function activates a smooth scroll to the top of the page when the back to top button is clicked */
$backToTop.on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
 $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 500);
 return false;
});
})



 <a href="#" class="back-to-top" style="display: inline;">
<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up">Back to Top</i> 
</a>

.back-to-top { 
background: none;
margin: 0;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
width: 160px;
height: 70px;
z-index: 100;
display: none;
text-decoration: none;
color: #ffffff;
background-color: #6eb1b5; 
box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
padding:25px;
}
.back-to-top i {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: By adding html+css you can help us to help you.

Comment: Sure. See edit above.

Comment: Version 53.0.2785.143 (64-bit) Chrome (osx) all working.

Comment: Hmm. that is the version I'm using and I still see that flicker when it has finished rolling to the top. It seems to happen consistently if I leave the cursor on the button?